# IF em StoredProcedure dentro de um select, remover sp_executesql @query

Tags: sql, sql-server, tsql

Tenho uma StoredProcedure que infelizmente somente por causa de um IF deixou de ser um select e virou tudo uma instrução VARCHAR e depois eu a executo, perdendo um dos principais benefícios do MSSQL que é a compilação.

*Modifiquei a SP apenas para ilustrar o problema:*

```
 ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[stp_Admin14_listagem_impressao]
        @intacao int,
        @IDCorretor int
    AS
    BEGIN

    declare @query nvarchar(max)

    set @query = 'SELECT  * from exemplo
    WHERE     intacao = '+  cast(@intacao as varchar) +') 

--// #### AQUI é o problema, o que fazer???
    if (@IDCorretor <> 0)
    BEGIN
        set @query  = @query + ' AND tbl_imoveis.int_CORRETOR = ' + cast(@IDCorretor as varchar)
    END


    exec sp_executesql @query
    END
```

Resumindo, se vier o parametro @IDCorretor <> 0 devo adicionar uma clausula where

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode manter a condição sempre na query, incluindo um **OR** para o parâmetro; isso dispensa o IF.

Fica mais ou menos assim:

```
...AND (@IDCorretor = 0 OR tbl_imoveis.int_CORRETOR = @IDCorretor)
```

Então, a stored procedure completa ficaria assim:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[stp_Admin14_listagem_impressao]
    @intacao int,
    @IDCorretor int
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT * from exemplo WHERE intacao = @intacao as varchar
    AND (@IDCorretor = 0 OR tbl_imoveis.int_CORRETOR = @IDCorretor)
END
```

Repare nos parênteses que eu adicionei. Não se esqueça deles!

#### Uma observação

> (...) perdendo um dos principais benefícios do MSSQL que é a
> compilação.

Você não perde nenhum benefício de performance por usar **sp_executesql** mas sim por concatenar os parâmetros na string em vez de utilizá-los como parâmetro de fato.

Veja como passar seus parâmetros em vez de concatená-los na query: [sp_executesql (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx).

Assim o plano de execução da query será reutilizado nas execuções subsequentes quando tiver havido alteração apenas no valor dos parâmetros.

Comment: normalmente eu utilizo o sp_executesql quando vou mandar um array, assim mando em formato texto e concateno tudo montando uma string e executando...

Comment: Seu código parece que funcionou, porém ainda não entendi como ele funcionou de fato.

Comment: Basicamente eu passei a lógica do IF para dentro da query. O teu **IF** diz: *"se o corretor informado for diferente de zero, então filtre os resultados com base neste corretor"*. O meu **OR** faz mais ou menos a mesma coisa: *"traga os corretores iguais ao do parâmetro ou, caso o parâmetro seja zero, tanto faz o corretor"*. Consegui explicar?

Comment: Sim, obrigado. Seria legal vc postar o código como ficou:

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[stp_Admin14_listagem_impressao]
        @ intacao int,
        @ IDCorretor int
    AS
    BEGIN


SELECT  * from exemplo
    WHERE     intacao = @intacao
AND (@IDCorretor = 0 OR tbl_imoveis.int_CORRETOR = (@IDCorretor))

Comment: a clausula where ficou errada no final pq vc colocou o cast, utilizei o cast só para a conversão de concatenação...
intacao = @intacao
AND (@IDCorretor = 0 OR tbl_imoveis.int_CORRETOR = (@IDCorretor))

Comment: @Dorathoto Certo. Eu estava mesmo estranhando estes CASTs mas não quis entrar no mérito :-)