# Fazer um IF para definir WHERE

Tags: sql-server, procedure

Preciso de uma ajuda com um comando em uma proc SQL.

Basicamente preciso de mais ou menos assim:

```
...
...

WHERE

IF ( @Id_ProductClass IS NULL  )
    WHERE CLIENTPROD.Id_ProductClass NOT IN (59, 150)
ELSE
    WHERE CLIENTPROD.Id_ProductClass = @Id_ProductClass
```

É possível fazer algo assim?

Answer (score 2):

Inclua a condição do **if** no próprio WHERE, assim:

```
WHERE
    (
        (@Id_ProductClass IS NOT NULL AND CLIENTPROD.Id_ProductClass = @Id_ProductClass)
        OR (@Id_ProductClass IS NULL AND CLIENTPROD.Id_ProductClass NOT IN (59, 150))
    )
    -- se não houver mais condições aqui, pode remover os parênteses mais externos.
```

Ou concatene uma string e utilize a stored procedure **sp_executesql** para executá-la, como fez o AP nesta [outra pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/47147/if-em-storedprocedure-dentro-de-um-select-remover-sp-executesql-query).

Ao optar por concatenar a query em uma string, não abra mão de utilizar parâmetros, conforme sugerido na [resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/47152/14584) daquela mesma pergunta.

Comment: Já usei um exemplo parecido em vez de usar IF. Muito boa a resposta.

Comment: Funcionou na medida.. Muito obrigado.